# Strange behaviour with double pipe operator and python virtualenv

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash build script which I run sourced so I can activate a Python virtual environment. I firstly run the unit-tests with `python3.7 -m unittest`. However, if these fail I don't want to run the main program. So, I need to deactivate the virtual environment (so the terminal is back to its original state) and then `return 1` to exit the build script.

So my script looks like this

```
# activate virtual env ...

python3.7 -m unittest || deactivate; return 1;
python3.7 app.py

deactivate
```

When the unit tests fail, `python3.7 -m unittest` returns `1` and the virtual environment deactivates as expected.

When the unit tests run successfully, `python3.7 -m unittest` returns `0`, however strangely the right side of the pipe seems to sort of run. I haven't figured out if it's an oddity with bash or with `deactivate` but here are some samples of the behaviour:

```
(exit 0) || deactivate; echo "Tests failed"; return 1; (Output: "Tests failed", deactivate not run)

(exit 0) || echo "Deactivating"; deactivate; echo "Tests failed"; return 1; (Output: "Tests failed", deactivate ran)

(exit 0) || echo "Tests failed"; return 1; (Output: Nothing, deactivate not run)
```

The last case of those three makes sense and follows expected behaviour, the other two do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to [Bash Pitfall 22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3), but not exactly the same. The important point is how the statements are grouped:

```
cmd1 || cmd2; cmd3
```

will run `cmd1`, and if the exit status is non-zero, `cmd2`; then, *no matter what*, `cmd3`.

The intention is rather this:

```
cmd1 || { cmd2; cmd3; }
```

If `cmd1` fails, run `cmd2` and `cmd3`.